# class only on one anchor and remove from all anchor in that ul

Tags: jquery

I have a UL in html which as following :

```
<ul class="most-populer">
  <li><a id="popular" class=" " href="#">Most Popular</a></li>
  <li><a id="price" href="#" class=" ">Price</a></li>
  <li><a id="rating" href="#" class=" ">Star Rating</a></li>
  <li><a id="alphabetic" href="#" class="active">Name</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using an ajax function to filter result based on these search criteria . thats working  fine for me . Now what i want that if user clicks on `popular` then only `popular` anchor tag have `active` class and removes from other anchor tag.

I know about [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) method of jquery

but i want to use them in that way if user clicks on any of link that UL only that anchor have `active` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz37w/1/)

```
$('ul.most-popular li a').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent def. anchor behavior !
    $('ul.most-popular').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: @rahularyansharma thanks I missed a `{` and the OP misspelled `most-populEr` instead of `most-popular`. FIXED

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".most-populer li a").on("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass("active").parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".most_populer a").click(function(e) {
    $(".most_populer a.active").removeClass("active"); // remove active classes
    $(this).addClass("active"); // add active class to clicked element
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default link behavior
});
```